# Python: How do I scan for a file, if it is not found, then add a new one?

Tags: python, file, while-loop

I am trying to make a program that writes a new file each time it runs.

For example:

I run the program once. The folder is empty so it adds a file to the folder named "Test_Number_1.txt"

I run the program for the second time. The folder has one file, so it scans it as a file, scans for another file but there is no file, so it creates a new file named "Test_Number_2.txt"

This is what I had in mind, but the code won't leave the while loop. I am still new to programming so excuse my inefficient coding haha.

```
memory = # something that changes each time I run the program
print(memory)
print("<-<<----<<<---------<+>--------->>>---->>->")
found_new = False
which_file = 0

while not found_new:
    try:
        file = open("path_to_folder/Test_Number_" + str(which_file) + ".txt", "a")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        which_file += 1
        file_w = open("path_to_folder/Test_Number_" + str(which_file) + ".txt", "w")
        found_new = True
        break
    print("Looked", which_file, "times.")
    which_file += 1
    time.sleep(1)
file = open("path_to_folder/Test_Number_" + str(which_file) + ".txt", "a")
file.write(memory)
file.close()
print("Done.")
```

I put the time.sleep(1) to delay the process in case of a bug so that my entire computer didn't overload and thank goodness because the program just keeps adding more and more files until I force quit it.

Comment: mode `a` will just go ahead and create the file even if it doesn't exist, so you'll never get the exception.

Comment: This solved my problem. I just replaced my "a" with "r".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple solution

```
from os.path import isfile

def file_n(n):
  return "Test_number_" + str(n) + ".txt"

n = 0
while isfile(file_n(n)):
  n += 1
f = open( file_n(n), "w" )
f.write("data...")
f.close()
```

The problem is that if many instances of that same program run at the same time, some files may be overwritten.